# Events for fs createReadStream Not Always Being Called

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, coffeescript, fs

I have an fs filestream being used to serve file downloads which are dynamically created.  I get this stream and pipe it to my response object after setting appropriate headers.

I also set a couple stream events so that if there's an error or the stream ends, it removes the generated files from the file system.

I'm running into an issue where, on occasion, when the download isn't correctly initialized or finished there may be some hanging files left on the file system.  I believe this is because of the events I hook into the stream.

My code:

```
stream = fs.createReadStream( fileName, {bufferSize: 64*1024})

had_error = false;
stream.on 'error', (err) ->
  had_error = err
stream.on 'close', ->
  if had_error
    console.log(had_error)

  fs.unlink fileName, (error) ->
    if error
      console.log("DELETE ERROR")
      console.log error

  fs.unlink dataFileName, (error) ->
    if error
      console.log("DELETE ERROR")
      console.log error
```

Checking on the [stream API](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream) documentation the 'close' event isn't called by all streams.  I would use the 'end' event, however according to the docs: `Indicates that no more 'data' events will happen. If the stream is also writable, it may be possible to continue writing.`

I'm worried if I were to use the 'end' event could you run into the issue where if I remove these files and the stream isn't finished writing to the http response that it will lead to a corrupt download.

Any "for sure" event that can be used as a catch to remove these files and not break downloads?

Worst case scenario I write a cronjob to remove these files (bleh).

Comment: Which Node.js version are you running on?

Comment: Okay, then I don't have an idea. But: In 0.9.x (and the upcoming 0.10.x) the behavior of read streams will change anyway. I guess that you will want to have a look at http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/ even if this does not solve your current problem.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the future info.  It looks like this issue only occurs if a user double clicks the link to the file.  Gonna give it a shot using the 'end' event and see if that fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Good luck with this :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks.  UNFORTUNATELY the different event doesn't fix the issue.  I'm guessing this may be because I have the route get this stream from another function and then uses that stream via a callback.  If someone double clicks it, the server response never fires, thus the 'end' event doesn't occur (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out a sure-fire way of ensuring the event gets called.  I'm guessing that if the `response` object never actually starts the stream, it never starts thus never having an ending event.  If anyone knows a workaround feel free to answer and get a free accepted answer.