# fs.createReadStream and .pipe()

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I'm trying to post a large file to another server using `request.post()` of the request package in Node.js and I'm getting:

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version    of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I thought it's because it's a big file (80MB) because the smaller files work fine, so I am now trying to implement a stream:

```
var options = {
    url: aURLIHaveDefined,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'MyRestAPI'
    },
    auth: {
        username: creds.username,
        password: creds.password
    },
    strictSSL: false,
    json: true
}

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePathIHaveDefined);

readStream.pipe(options);
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Does anyone know the syntax to include options in the pipe and why I'm getting this error?

**UPDATE (after sousa comment):**
I tried:

```
readStream.pipe(request(options));
readStream.on('end', function() {
     console.log('end of readStream'+fileName);
});
```

It doesn't error out but it also doesn't seem to do anything now. The program just executes and I never see the `console.log()` ?

**UPDATE #2:**

Using the help manual [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request), found that you can do this:

```
fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.put('http://....'))
```

So I added the `request.post()` inside the pipe and it seems like I'm almost there! Using:

```
readStream.pipe(
    request.post(options, 
         function(error, response, data) {  

                if (error) {
                    console.log(": Cannot upload file to " + creds.server + " due to " + error);
                    setImmediate(failureCallback(error)); 
                } else {
                    console.log(": file uploaded to " + data);
                    // send back data, which is url of uploaded file
                    setImmediate( successCallback(data) ); 
                }
            }
        )
    );
```

I get an error saying the length needs to be known:

> Apache Tomcat/5.5.17 - Error report HTTP Status 411 - Length Required
>   his request cannot be handled without a defined content length (Length
>   Required).

Answer (score 5):

The options var needs to be a stream. You have to do something like this:

```
readStream.pipe(request(options))
```

You're piping to an object, that's why you have no method `on`.

Comment: Your end event is not being fired. Probably your request is not working properly, meaning that the readStream never reaches the end.

This is a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163567/events-for-fs-createreadstream-not-always-being-called)

Comment: try to get your `end` event from the read file stream like this:

    readStream.on('end', function () {
      console.log('end!')
    });

    readStream.pipe(process.stdout);

If this works, then you're probably doing something wrong with your `request`.

Comment: Hey I think the problem was that it needs to be request.post() so I actually post something but I still get the length error outlined above. Thanks for sticking with this we are close!

Comment: I'm trying this form-data approach now: https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/396

Answer (score 0):

For Update #2:
Request github says
"request can also pipe to itself. When doing so, content-type and content-length are preserved in the PUT headers"

I do not need to set headers, however if Apache Tomcat is complaining you can always set the Content-Length as follows:

```
    var stats = fs.statSync('file.json');
```

And then in the option headers:

```
    Content-Length':stats.size
```